# Setting the form as dirty without actually changing a value?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to set a CRM form as dirty (so with pending changes) without actually changing a value in the form?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by this?

Comment: I'm trying to make the duplicate detection window to show up... if I can't find a better way I can try to make a fake save, but I don't want to actually change the data so... It's related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42411924/is-there-a-way-to-open-the-duplicate-detection-window-in-crm-using-javascript-an

Comment: What about `.setSubmitMode('always') ` on a field ?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work unfortunately. I'm starting to believe that is not possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. (B.t.w. a more common requirement is setting the form as NOT dirty, which is not possible either.)

The form actually tracks the state of the entity it displays by comparing the original and modified attribute values. This behaviour cannot be changed in a supported way.

Comment: Yeah, I finally came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the confirmation :)